# onsubmit cakephp icon change function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

```
 <div class="bit-4 pad-small">
    <label>Cheque No</label>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('cheque_no',array('label'=>false,'class'=>'custom-select','options' =>'' ,'empty' => '','required'));  ?> 
    <span>required</span>
  </div> 
   <div class="bit-4 pad-small">
    <label>DD No</label>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('dd_no',array('label'=>false,'class'=>'custom-select','options' =>'' ,'empty' => '','required'));  ?> 
    <span>required</span>
  </div> 
 <div class="bit-4 pad-small"  style="float:none;">
        <br>
        <br>
     <?php echo $this->Form->input('approve', array(
                              'type'=>'checkbox', 
                               'style' => 'float:left;',
                               'label'=>'Approval of order',
                              'format' => array('before', 'input', 'between', 'label', 'after', 'error' ) 
       ) ); ?>
        <span>required</span>
       </div>
      <div class="bit-12" >
        <input type="submit"   value="Submit" class="form-submit button" />
      </div> 
    </div>
```

when i click on submit if i click approve a green tick has to be displayed else a red tick has to be displayed..What sholud i do?

Comment: You need to make jQuery function on approve checkbox change and perform btn color their as per condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `onChangeApprove` function **onchange** event of "**Approve button**".

```
function onChangeApprove(thisObj) {
    if ($(thisObj).is(":checked")) {
        //change btn color to Green
         $("#imgControl").attr("src","/../img/green.png")  

    } else {
        //change btn color to Red
         $("#imgControl").attr("src","/../img/red.png")  
    }
}
```

Comment: 'onchange' => "javascript:onChangeApprove(this);",

Comment: Which image src do you need to change add a id for that image control and $("#imgControl").attr("src","/../img/red.png") or green.

Comment: Page should not post back for this.If page post pack and then you will get approved tick true value then you need to perform $("#approve").change() on dom ready.

Comment: 1. Make 'id'=> ''approve"  2. Add $("#approve").change() at $(document).ready(fucntion(){  $("#approve").change();  })

Comment: i am getting automatically move this discussion to chat?but getting error to move to chat.

Comment: Does your code submitted and you will get approve check box checked?

Comment: $("#imgControl").attr("src","/../img/green.png")

Comment: After get all data you need to make color red/green at edit time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97364/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-user).